# Tails installer packages missing?

Tags: linux

I want to install Linux Tails. I already added ppa:tails-team/tails-installer to my sources, but when my Ubuntu Software Center tries to download the repository information, I get this error:

> W:Failed to fetch
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/tails-team/tails-installer/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages
>   404  Not Found , W:Failed to fetch
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/tails-team/tails-installer/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages
>   404  Not Found , E:Some index files failed to download. They have been
>   ignored, or old ones used instead.

I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
If you follow the link up to tails-installer/ubuntu/dists/ you can see that "trusty" is missing.

Any idea on what to do? Should I just wait?

Comment: While I hope you find the answer you are looking for, you may find [this community](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) better suited to answer your question. Best of luck!

Comment: @Spyder_Says_hi I didn't know about that, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got an answer from the Tails support team saying that you will need to download the Tails installer packages from ubuntu 15.10, although I was using ubuntu 14.04.

Works now.